# Interface can not call self method

Tags: pointers, go, methods, interface

I have defined two functions. When I pass a pointer to it, I can't get the defined method. Why is this?

```
type Visitor interface {
    work()
}

func test(v *Visitor)  {
    v.work() // error
}


func test1(v Visitor)  {
    v.work() // ok
}
```

Error:

> v.work undefined (type *Visitor is pointer to interface, not
>   interface)

anyone know why, ths

Comment: error msg: v.work undefined (type *Visitor is pointer to interface, not interface)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func test(v *Visitor)  {
    v.work() // error
}
```

`v.work()` ought to be a method call. But `v` is of type `*Visitor`, a pointer to interface. **A pointer to interface has 0 methods, it does not implement anything** (except the empty interface `interface{}`).

When using a non-pointer, the value `v` (or rather its type) has a method `work()`, so you can call that:

```
func test(v Visitor)  {
    v.work() // ok
}
```

Here `v.work()` works, because the `v` is of type `Visitor` which is an interface, and it contains the method `work()`.

What may be confusing is that if you add method to a (non-pointer, non-interface) concrete type, the respective pointer type will also have that method, and you can call that. This is in [Spec: Method sets:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> A type may have a *method set* associated with it. The method set of an [interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) is its interface. The method set of any **other** type `T` consists of all [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) declared with receiver type `T`. **The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).** Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields, as described in the section on [struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). Any other type has an empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a [unique](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Uniqueness_of_identifiers) non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) [method name](https://golang.org/ref/spec#MethodName).

The difference is that you tried the same with interface type, which won't work. It works with concrete (non-interface) types. Lesson is to never use pointer to interface unless you can reason why it is needed (it is rarely needed).

Answer (score -2):

As the error clearly states:

> v.work undefined (type *Visitor is pointer to interface, not
>   interface)

This is because the work() function is called on pointer to the receiver but defined on value.

```
type Visitor interface {
    work()
}
```

But you are passing pointer type receiver in second case in which you are getting an error.

In Golang spec [Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) are defined as:

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set
>   of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of T). Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields,
>   as described in the section on struct types. Any other type has an
>   empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
>   non-blank method name.

One approach you can do is Implement the interface by using the struct on which you can call the method work().

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Visitor struct{}

type Visit interface {
    work()
}

func test(v Visit)  {
    v.work() // error
    fmt.Printf("%+v", v)
}

func (v *Visitor) work(){}


func main(){
       v := Visitor{}
       test(&v)
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VmEB37Tn71O)

Comment: No- that would result in a different error. You are mixing up pointers related to the type that implements the interface vs a pointer to the interface type.

Comment: @nos First In golang you should never create pointer to interface.

Comment: ofcourse not, but that is what the OP has done, and that is what the question is about.

Comment: @nos the OP is getting error because the reason is method sets. he is calling work method on v interface of pointer type.

Comment: @nos If you have something which I can learn please share it with me. I love to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @nos Can you even call a method with receiver without even defining it. I do not think so it is possible. But you are saying you  can call a method on interface type receiver without even creating the type.

Comment: No, I and you, are saying that one cannot call a method on `*Visitor` , where Visitor is an interface and you have a pointer to the interface. But you are answering something different than what the OP asks about, and your code defines `Vistor` as a struct, not an interface later on. You also have a `func (v Visitor) work(){}` function at the beginning of your question, which you can not do, since the OP defined `Visitor` as an interface, not a struct.