# Passing an interface pointer in a function parameter

Tags: function, go, struct, parameters, interface

I am trying to understand Golang (1.12) interfaces. I found out that interface pointers must be explicitly dereferenced, unlike structs:

```
import "fmt"

// A simple interface with one function
type myinter interface {
    hello()
}

// Implement myinter
type mystruct struct {}

func (mystruct) hello() {
    fmt.Println("I am T!")
}

// Some function that calls the hello function as defined by myinter
func callHello(i *myinter) {   
    i.hello()  // <- cannot resolve reference 'hello'
}

func main() {
    newMystruct := &mystruct{}
    callHello(newMystruct)
}
```

Here, my `callHello` function cannot resolve the reference to my `hello` function as defined in the interface. Of course, dereferencing the interface works:

```
func callHello(i *myinter) {   
    (*i).hello()  // <- works!
}
```

But in structs, we can call the function directly, [none of this cumbersome dereference notation is necessary](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/4):

```
func callHello(s *mystruct) {   
    s.hello()  // <- also works!
}
```

Why is this the case? Is there a reason why we must explicitly dereference `interface` pointers? Is Go trying to discourage me from passing `interface` pointers into functions?

Comment: It's rare to use a pointer to an interface in Go. Nothing in the question indicates that there's a reason to use a pointer to an interface.  Fix by changing `*myinter` to `myinter`. This fixes the error  at `callHello(newMystruct)` and at `i.hello()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface can not call self method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774819/interface-can-not-call-self-method),

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the way the type system works. An interface type `I` defines a method set. The method set is defined for type `I`, and not for type `*I`. Because of this, the use of `*I` is limited. It can be used when a function is to set the interface value, but it is rare:

```
func f(x *error) {
  *x = fmt.Errorf("Some error")
}
```

Note that the interface itself can have an underlying pointer value:

```
func f(x someInterface) {
   *x.(*someType) = value
}

func main() {
   x := someType{}
   f(&x)
}
```

This is different for non-interface types. When you define a method for a non-interface type `T`, the method is defined for both `T` and `*T`. If you define a method for `*T`, it is only defined for `*T`, and not for `T`.

Comment: But if I want to take an interface as a parameter in a function, wouldn't it be inefficient to pass a concrete type in by value? Interfaces represent abstract types, wouldn't passing a pointer be better than passing by value especially when we don't know the size of the concrete type?

Comment: If you pass an interface to a function, what's passed is the pointer to the underlying value, and a pointer to the type. If the underlying value of the interface is a struct (not pointer), interface points to a copy of the struct. If you pass a concrete struct to the function, the struct will be copied. If you pass a pointer to the struct, only a pointer will be passed. So passing in a struct takes a copy, regardless if you pass it via an interface or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Go trying to discourage me from passing interface pointers into functions?

Yes.

Pointer-to-interface is *wrong* in (almost*) all cases.

(* There are very rare and delicate cases where pointer-to-interface makes sense but chances are high you won't see them more than once every 5 years.)

(Nitpick: The language is called "Go". "golang.org" is the website. Basics like this are covered by the compatibility promise and do not depend on the version: Go 1.0, 1.12 and 1.16 behave exactly the same in this regard.)

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* this is wrong? Coming from a heavy Java development past, it seems that interface pointers would be more common (passing pointers to abstract types).

Comment: @KennyWorden Pointer-to-something is needed if you want to mutate the something. An interface value itself is seldomly modified. What is modified is the actual value contained _in_ the interface value: It is common to store pointers inside an interface, but that is completely different from a pointer to an interface value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the pointer and use the interface.

```
func callHello(i myinter) {   
    i.hello()  
}
```

This func will now accept either an instance of a struct that implements the interface, or a pointer to an instance of a struct that implements the interface.

```
func main() {
    instance := mystruct{}
    pointer := &mystruct{}
    callHello(instance)
    callHello(pointer)
}
```

outputs the following:

```
I am T!
I am T!
 
Program exited.
```